# Trying namespaced functions Jquery: Syntax Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, namespaces

I'm trying to change my approach in writing javascript as I did with PHP. Here is the old code that I check it's working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var calculatetotalwidth = $('#container').width()
    var calculatesegment = calculatetotalwidth / 5
    var calculaterating = calculatesegment * rating

    $('#ratings .ratingbar').animate({width:calculaterating},1200);
});
```

It's simply a animation that will mimic a progressbar that will display my rating, by segmenting the width of the content div and divide it by the scope I choose (which is 5/5 in this case).

Here is my OOP approach on the problem.

```
var RatingsBar = {

    fadeOptions: {
    slow: 5000,
    medium: 2500,
    fast: 1200
    },

    Calculate: function (contaierid, score, scope) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var calculatetotalwidth = $(contaierid).width()
        var calculatesegment = calculatetotalwidth / scope
        var calculaterating = calculatesegment * score

        $('#ratings .ratingbar').animate({
        width: calculaterating
        }, RatingsBar.fadeOptions.slow);

    });

    } 
}

RatingsBar.Calculate('#container', ratings, 5)
```

I used the source code pattern in jqueryslideslidemenu plugin. I can't seem to make it work. Am I missing something here?

I got the thing to work. The problem now, is that I need ratings to be used. I took it from a PHP code here:

```
    class rating_system {

    var $score;

    function __construct($rate) {
        $this->score = $rate;
    }

    function run_rate() {
        $this->phptojava();
        echo $this->displayrate();
    }


    function phptojava() {
        echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> var ratings ='. $this->score ."</script>";
    }

    function displayrate() {
        $wrapper = '<div id="ratings"><div class="ratingbar">';
        $wrapper = $wrapper . '<p>' . $this->score . '<p>';
        $wrapper = $wrapper . '</div>' . '<div class="blankrating">' . '<p>' . 'ratings' . '<p>';
        $wrapper = $wrapper . '</div></div>';

        return $wrapper;
    }

}

$view = new rating_system(4);
```

Thanks everyone. I manage to get it working.

```
<html>
<head>

<?php

    class rating_system {

        var $score;

        function __construct($rate) {
            $this->score = $rate;
        }

        function run_rate() {
            $this->phptojava();
            echo $this->displayrate();
        }


        function phptojava() {
            echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> var ratings ='. $this->score ."</script>";
        }

        function displayrate() {
            $wrapper = '<div id="ratings"><div class="ratingbar">';
            $wrapper = $wrapper . '<p>' . $this->score . '<p>';
            $wrapper = $wrapper . '</div>' . '<div class="blankrating">' . '<p>' . 'ratings' . '<p>';
            $wrapper = $wrapper . '</div></div>';

            return $wrapper;
        }

    }

    $view = new rating_system(2);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var RatingsBar = {
    fadeOptions: {slow:5000,medium:2500,fast:1200},
    calculate: function (contaierid, score, scope) {
//      $(document).ready(function() {
                var calculatetotalwidth = $(contaierid).width();
                var calculatesegment = calculatetotalwidth / scope;
                var calculaterating = calculatesegment * score;
                $('#ratings .ratingbar').animate({width:calculaterating}, RatingsBar.fadeOptions.fast);
//          });//end ready function
    }//End Calculate Function
} //end object

$(document).ready(function() { 
    RatingsBar.calculate('#container',ratings,5);

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">

#container {
    height:500px;
    width:720px;

}

#ratings {
    width:720px;
    height:75px;
    position:relative;

    float:left;
}

#ratings .ratingbar {
    width:0px;
    border: 1px #910000 solid;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #A62E10 47%, #F52D00 82%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #A62E10 47%, #F52D00 82%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #A62E10 47%, #F52D00 82%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #A62E10 47%, #F52D00 82%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #A62E10 47%, #F52D00 82%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.47, #A62E10),
        color-stop(0.82, #F52D00)
    );

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#A62E10', endColorstr='#F52D00');
}

#ratings .blankrating {
    text-align:left;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<?php echo $view->run_rate(); ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This one is the entire code I'm trying.

Comment: This is effectively namespaced functions, not OOP :P

Comment: Oh. Thanks, but why doesn't it work?

Comment: Hard to tell.. what is `Ratings`.. it's not in the code

Comment: This example has nothing to do with OOP. It is JSON style name spacing. Calculate should be calculate because it is not a constructor here.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: @WojciechBednarski Changing Calculate to calculate worked! but I need the rating variable. I'll expand the codebase, ratings is taken from a PHP variable.

Comment: @DemianBrecht Can you recommend me a good debugger?

Comment: Firebug (firefox) or Chrome's developer tools (F12 in FF once you've installed it, or Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would work, hard to tell without a working test case.

```
var RatingsBar = {

    fadeOptions: {
    slow: 5000,
    medium: 2500,
    fast: 1200
    },

    Calculate: function (contaierid, score, scope) {
        var calculatetotalwidth = $(contaierid).width();
        var calculatesegment = calculatetotalwidth / scope;
        var calculaterating = calculatesegment * score;

        $('#ratings .ratingbar').animate({
        width: calculaterating
        }, RatingsBar.fadeOptions.slow);
    } 
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    RatingsBar.Calculate('#container', Ratings, 5);
});
```

Try reproducing your problem on jsfiddle.net and post the link.

Edit : What is Ratings supposed to be (second argument in your function call)? Replace Ratings by any value or define a Ratings variable and the code above works.

Comment: This worked. When I removed the ready function inside the property it took the ratings variable that was taken from a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jsHint codechecker](http://www.jshint.com%22)

I have already checked the code for you, here is the report:
http://www.jshint.com/reports/65020

You have missed the round brackets behind the function statement:

```
Line 4: $(document).ready(function {
Expected '(' and instead saw '{'.
```

Please fix the syntax-errors and post the code again ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about the Ratings param? Replace it for one number to see...

```
RatingsBar.Calculate('#container', 10, 5)
```

Comment: It worked. But I need the ratings variable. I expanded the codebase on how I got the ratings variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var ratingsBar = {};

    ratingsBar.fadeOptions: {
        slow: 5000,
            medium: 2500,
            fast: 1200
        };

    ratingsBar.calculate: function (contaierid, score, scope) {

            //$(document).ready(function () {

                var calculate

totalwidth = $(contaierid).width(),
                calculatesegment = calculatetotalwidth / scope,
                calculaterating = calculatesegment * score;

            $('#ratings .ratingbar').animate(
                {
                    width:calculaterating
                },
                ratingsBar.fadeOptions.slow
            );

        //});

    };

ratingsBar.calculate('#container', Ratings, 5);
```

Try this one, it should work. The main problem wast that you bind function to document ready after this event :- )

Another thing is there is missing few semicolons.

I'm not entirely sure that ratingsBar.fadeOptions.slow was defined at this time, so I've changed a little your name spacing.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous typos preventing this to work:
`Ratings` is undefined in `RatingsBar.Calculate('#container', Ratings, 5)`
missing semicolons on the var in the Calculate function.

So, I just refactored it to be how I would do it.

```
var RatingsBar = {
    speeds: {
        slow: 5000,
        medium: 2500,
        fast: 1200
    },
    calculate: function (container, score, outOf) {
        var $container = $(container),
            ratio = score / outOf,
            rating = Math.floor($container.width() * ratio);

        $container.find('.ratingbar').animate({width: rating}, this.speeds.slow);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var score = 2,
        outOf = 5;

    RatingsBar.calculate('#container', score, outOf);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="ratingbar"></div>
</div>

#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

CSS

```
#container .ratingbar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Either way to calculate the width of the `.ratingbar` works. It just made more sense to me this way.

Comment: Its not undefined. I placed the variable passed from a PHP object.

Comment: what's the difference if you put the ready function inside the script than putting it as you had stated?

Comment: @MrA - I believe it is cleaner to separate the function of calculating the rating from the event of loading. It allows you to run RatingsBar.Calculate anytime you need to–like updating with ajax.  By pulling it out, the RatingsBar object only reacts to itself.

Comment: I'm starting to get it. Thanks.